# How to set the requirement level for a field

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-4

Following [this blog](http://ronaldlemmen.blogspot.se/2007/07/change-requirement-level-at-runtime.html) I'm trying to set the requirement level to business recommended but I fail miserably. I only get the the red star indicating that the field is business required.

```
crmForm.SetFieldReqLevel("new_bamsegurka", 0);
crmForm.SetFieldReqLevel("new_bamsegurka", 1);    
crmForm.SetFieldReqLevel("new_bamsegurka", 2);
```

The first line turns the red star off. The other two, turn it on. There's no seemingly way to set the blue cross, though... What do I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already found the right code to set a field business recommended (blue cross) is with parameter 2

```
crmForm.SetFieldReqLevel("new_bamsegurka", 2);
```

It can be an issue with the rollup of your CRM 4.0 environment. I saw a similar bug (a required didn't set properly by javascript) with a CRM 2011 with an early rollup.

For the corresponding operation of getting requirement level of a field, there's no supported method. One needs to hack around as follows.

```
crmForm.all["new_bamsegurka_c"].className.indexOf("Rec") >= 0
```

Note the *_c* part as well as *Rec*, as opposed to *Req*.

Comment: Oh, you mean it's recommended **although** it shows required? Sneaky sucker... How can I check if it's really so? There's no *GetFieldRequirementLevel* method...

Comment: you can try to save and check if the field is prompted as required. Did you try the alternative to modify directly the DOM? because it's CRM 4.0 and it works only with IE you can write all the nasty code you want :)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I mean - how do I programmatically check that a field is business recommended? It seems that *SetFieldReqLevel* works for **setting** but I can't find anything for **getting** the level, nothing like *GetFieldReqLevel* in sight...

Comment: the only way in CRM 4.0 is to retrieve the DOM attribute using a getElementById, check its visibility status and hoping it wasn't messed up by some other javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try,

```
// Requirement level

crmForm.all.new_bamsegurka.setAttribute("req", 2);
crmForm.all.new_bamsegurka_c.className = "req";
crmForm.all.new_bamsegurka_c.innerHTML = crmForm.all.new_bamsegurka_c.innerText + "<img  alt='Required' src='/_imgs/frm_required.gif'/>";

crmForm.all.new_bamsegurka.setAttribute("req", 1);
crmForm.all.new_bamsegurka_c.className = "n";
crmForm.all.new_bamsegurka_c.innerHTML = crmForm.all.new_bamsegurka_c.innerText + "<img  alt='Recommended' src='/_imgs/frm_recommended.gif'/>";

crmForm.all.new_bamsegurka.setAttribute("req", 0);
crmForm.all.new_bamsegurka_c.className = "n";
crmForm.all.new_bamsegurka_c.innerHTML = crmForm.all.new_bamsegurka_c.innerText;
```

This should be a better fit.
Be sure to change only the "new_bamsegurka" for each to match your field name.